# Show that $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\},...\}$ is a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I show that  $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\},...\}$ is a set using the ZFC axioms only?

I know that $S(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$. How could I prove the above strictly?

Comment: Personally, I don't understand what the sentence "I know that $S(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$" is supposed to mean.

Comment: @Gae.S. This is a notion that is called, the "successor set". I thought it was a well known notion.

Comment: Perhaps, but the standard one (so to say, von Neumann's) is $S(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$ and $S(S(\emptyset))=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$

Answer (score 5):

Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define recursively

$$S(0) = \emptyset, \quad S(n+1) = \{S(n)\}$$

By the axiom of replacement (and subset comprehension), $\{S(n): n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a set.

Comment: But by taking a subset of $\Bbb N$, you're assuming the existence of the set $\Bbb N$

Comment: Yes, that is the axiom of infinity. We have ZFC at our disposal.

Comment: I do not think the set we are given is $\mathbb{N}$. For me $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies $\emptyset \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{N} \implies x \cup \{x\} \in \mathbb{N}$ which is not the case here (I use the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers)

Comment: You're right; I guess I just saw all the brackets and lost track. Thanks for humoring me

Comment: Thanks alot! How should I cite the axiom of replacement and subset comprehension in this case? Im having trouble with providing a clear and formal proof

Comment: In the linked duplicate, a commenter speaks of having read a definition from before Neumann where the definition at the time *was* that $S(x)=\{x\}$ and $0=\emptyset$ in which case $0=\emptyset, 1=\{0\},2=\{1\},3=\{2\},\dots$ rather than $S(x)=x\cup\{x\}$ in which case the set in question according to those definitions *is* $\Bbb N$.

Comment: As such, I think it necessary to request information from the OP as to what axioms are being used, how the natural numbers are being defined, etc... as I agree that this seems suspiciously circular.

Comment: The axiom of infinity only asserts the existence of *some* infinite set, not necessarily equal to either of the two sets mentioned here. Of course one can *prove* they're sets.